# How many ways to distribute 100 DIFFERENT objects to 8 people (DIFFERENT), while each one cannot have more than 40?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

I know that if you want just to distribute 100 DIFFERENT objects to 8 people the formula is $8^{100}$, but what if you have to give from 0 to 40 to each..?

Iam very confused...

Comment: Try scaling the problem: Try distributing 12 items to 5 people, with nobody getting more than 4. (or similar). What tricks to you know do deal with these sorts of problems? (I'm thinking inclusion exclusion could work, also maybe stars and bars, but haven't tried anything yet)

Comment: Iam still confused about how am I going to do this.I really cannot find an answer. I think the solution is too complex.... Iam not such good in combinatorics generally. Is there any formula , or I have to combine some functions..?

Comment: Is this a textbook problem or have you devised it ?